# How to convert a failed computation to a successful one and vice versa

Tags: haskell, typeclass, alternative-functor, monadplus

<sub>This might very well be a solution seeking a problem ... if so, I beg your indulgence!</sub>

Possible implementation:

```
class Switch' f where
  switch :: f a -> f ()

instance Switch' [] where
  switch []     = [()]
  switch (_:_)  = []

instance Switch' Maybe where
  switch Nothing   = Just ()
  switch (Just _)  = Nothing
```

The interpretation would be:  given a successful computation, make it a failing one; given a failing computation, make it a successful one.  I'm not sure, but this seems like it might be sort of the opposite of MonadPlus ... if you squint really hard. ???

Is there a standard typeclass or some other implementation for this concept?  What would the  underlying math look like, if any (i.e. is this a semigroup, a loop, etc.)?

Comment: `switch` is almost an element of order two - it's almost self inverse, in that `switch.switch.switch` = `switch.switch`. It generates eventually repeating orbits (although eventually is the correct word, it sounds lengthy when referring to a wait of 1 iteration). `switch.switch` is idempotent. That's all the maths I thought of to throw at switch just now.

Comment: What makes `[()]` the right thing to return, rather than, say, `[(),()..]`?

Comment: It's `return ()`, like the other example.

Comment: @AndrewC Maybe the law could be that `switch` specialized to `m () -> m ()` is an [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)).

Comment: @PetrPudlák Yes, I think that's the perfect way of putting it. Good call. Since `switch :: Switch m => m a -> m ()`, we know `switch x :: m ()`, so then all the ones I said hold automatically. Very neat. Also involution is a nicer term than the ones I used.

Comment: @AndrewC I realized that this involution law is infeasible. Let's consider `switch` for `[]`. Then everything of type `[()]` (like `[(),(),()]`) must be mapped to `[]`, so `switch` isn't injective and so it doesn't have an inverse. Stating that `switch . switch . switch = switch` seems much more reasonable. We also need something to say that `switch` flips (to rule out things like `switch = const something`). We could require that `switch (return x) = mzero` and/or `switch mzero = return ()`. Seems to me that these two last conditions could be sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

```
switch :: (Alternative f, Eq (f a)) => f a -> f ()
switch x | x == empty = pure ()
         | otherwise = empty
```

or

```
switch :: (MonadPlus m, Eq (m a)) => m a -> m ()
switch x | x == mzero = return ()
         | otherwise = mzero
```

Comment: @MattFenwick my mistake, I've fixed them up.

Comment: The `Eq` constraint is unfortunate

Comment: When my data structures contain functions, or something else not `Eq`-able, what should I do?

Comment: @MattFenwick Not sure.  It's almost like we want an `isEmpty` for `Monoid`/`Alternative`.  Or some typeclass that let's us do an "outer-Eq" where `outereq :: f a -> f b -> Bool`

Answer (score 4):

I've got a generic solution but it can only work for `MonadPlus` instances that obey the [left catch](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/MonadPlus) law (and that's probably only a necessary condition, not sufficient):

```
isZero :: (MonadPlus m) => m a -> m Bool
isZero x = (x >> return False) `mplus` return True

switch :: (MonadPlus m) => m a -> m ()
switch x = isZero x >>= \r -> if r then return () else mzero
```

It works for [`STM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/stm/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-STM.html#t:STM) too.

(For lists it always returns `[()]` though, I'd say this definition won't work for anything that is satisfies left distribution.)

It's not possible to define it in this way for `Applicative`s, because `switch` inspects the value of `isZero`, and applicatives cannot do that. (And, `MonadPlus` instances that satisfy the left-catch rule [rarely satisfy](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/14143/10336) `Applicative` laws.)

Anyhow it'd be interesting to see if `switch . (switch :: m () -> m ()) = id` holds for this definition.

Answer (score 3):

I found a completely different answer, and that is [the `LogicT` monad transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/logict). It has [`lnot`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/logict/0.5.0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Logic-Class.html#v%3alnot) defined as:

> ```
> lnot :: MonadLogic m => m a -> m ()
> ```
>
> Inverts a logic computation. If `m` succeeds with at least one value, `lnot
>   m` fails. If `m` fails, then `lnot m` succeeds the value `()`.

I believe this is exactly what you wanted.